# Does a resource dictionary have to be explicitly referenced?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, resourcedictionary, app.xaml

I have the following in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="BasicStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BasicStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
</Style>
```

I then tried to use the button style in MainPage.xaml like so:

...but at runtime I get, "*Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key ButtonStyle*"

Do I have to formally introduce MainPage.xaml to the ResourceDictionary?

Does the ResourceDirectionary have to be referenced in MainPage, or from within App.xaml, or...???

### UPDATE

So just what is the proper XML for Application.Resources inside App.xaml?

Using the idea from robertos below, after adding a resource dictionary to my project and naming it "GlobalStylesResourceDictionary.xaml", I added this to App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="GlobalStylesResourceDictionary.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

...so that my entire App.xaml is:

```
<Application x:Class="Photrax.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="using:Photrax">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ai:TelemetryContext x:Key="ApplicationInsightsBootstrapper" xmlns:ai="using:Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GlobalStylesResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

However, with this I get "Each dictionary entry must have an associated key."

Yet this comes [in]directly from Microsoft (robertos took the XAML he shows below from the ms page he references). So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reference the ResourceDictionary either in MainPage.xaml or App.xaml, using something like:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--other resources can be here-->
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="rd1.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="rd2.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

More information: [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968442.aspx)